# Silverstripe 3: How to remove html text from GridField in EditForm view?

Tags: html, view, grid, silverstripe, summary

Good morning,

I have a DataObject that has an 'HTMLText' field in it as a description.
However, when it's displayed in the backend in the Summary View, I'm seeing all the HTML code associated with it. How can I strip the HTML Code and display the text alone or a summary of the text without the HTML tags?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the casting in the GF config per Field:

```
$GridField->getConfig()->getComponentByType("GridFieldDataColumns")->setFieldCasting(array("FieldWithHTML"=>"HTMLText->BigSummary"));
```

Answer (score 5):

[Summary fields](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/dataobject#summary-fields) can be used to show a quick overview of the data for a specific `DataObject` record.

To include field manipulations in your summaries, you can use a dot-notation.

```
private static $summary_fields = array(
    'Title' => 'Title',
    'Description.BigSummary' => 'Description'
);
```

Make sure to call `?flush=1` to have this property loaded or updated.

Comment: Very elegant solution. This works as well. The only thing with this method is the parsing of '&' it shows it as html-code-entity '&amp;'. Other than that it's nice. Also, '?flush=all' doesn't seem to really flush the cache in version 3. I've hit a wall with that already and when I used '?flush=1' it works for me in 3. Thanks.

Comment: I've just decided to try [munomono's] "BigSummary" cast in place of your "Description.Summary", which gives me "Description.BigSummary" and this fusion works. Exactly like [munomono's] solution, except it's less work :)

Comment: @user3298383 - I've made the changes as you've suggested from your comments. Glad it helped. Yeah the `$summary_fields` are nice and easy and pretty flexible. You can even call functions to return custom data in there.